# Minimal linux distro for compiling arm binaries

Tags: c++, linux, arm

I have this setup:
A windows/x86 development box and a PandaBoard ES for testing with a linux on it.
I would like to ask you for recommending a linux distribution that I would run in Hyper-V on my devbox that would be used only for compiling arm/linux binaries. After compiling these binaries I will copy them to an SD Memory Card and test them on PandaBoard.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered doing a cross compile from windows or does this not work in your scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Zenwalk](http://www.zenwalk.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=126) for whenever I need a **real** linux box (2.6 kernel + XFCE 4.8). It's not really a minimal distro (in the sense that [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org) and [Puppy](http://puppylinux.org) are), but it feels fast and snappy in VirtualBox 4.1 with 1GB RAM allocated to it . The machine runs on a Windows 7 x64 host with a total of 4GB of RAM with hardware virtualization support and nested paging.

If you're going to use Linux frequently and/or for extended periods of time, why not consider dual booting with Windows rather than running it inside a VM?

Also, have you considered [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)? It provides quite a [few](http://cygwin.com/packages/) linux tools on a Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not considering dual booting, because I already have an established Windows devbox na Linux is only one of the targets that my software is targeting among all the arm-based platforms that I'm supporting.

Comment: Understood, edited my post to include the Cygwin option. Have you considered that?